# make error > depends on non-existent package gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have gazebo , i installed gazebo with synaptic and i can open it with "$gazebo" in terminal.
when i make hector_gazebo_plugins package, it gave me this error :( any body help?

```
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~/fuerte_workspace/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins$ make
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package hector_gazebo_plugins
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests hector_gazebo_plugins
[rospack] Error: package/stack hector_gazebo_plugins depends on non-existent package gazebo


CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
  


  Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
  'hector_gazebo_plugins'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
  Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~/fuerte_workspace/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_gazebo/hector_gazebo_plugins$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59147/make-error-%3E-depends-on-non-existent-package-gazebo/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each ROS distro is built with its own consistent copy of Gazebo, plus some plugins for working in a ROS environment.

To install the Fuerte version on Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo
```

**EDIT**: looks like your problem is with the Hector plugins, themselves. Does this help?

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-hector-gazebo
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-25**:
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo
[sudo] password for mohsen:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-fuerte-simulator-gazebo is already the newest version.

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-25**:
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
ttf-umefont libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386 ttf-unfonts-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$

## **Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-25**:\

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-25**:
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-hector-gazebo
[sudo] password for mohsen:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-fuerte-hector-gazebo is already the newest version.

**Comment by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on 2013-03-25**:
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
ttf-umefont libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 wine-gecko1.4 wine-gecko1.4:i386 ttf-unfonts-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
mohsen@mohsen-ThinkPad-R500:~$

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-26**:
If you already had the package installed, why are you trying to build it?